# Apache / Httpd.conf - How do I set an Option that applies to all VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

How do I set all docroots to FollowSymLinks? I have a bunch of virtual host entries and don't want to modify each one.

**Edit:** I added 'Options +FollowSymLinks' in .htaccess and httpd.conf but I still receive 403 (Forbidden) errors :(. I even tried following SymLinks on twitter, but that didn't work either. http://twitter.com/SymLinks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your virtual hosts are all under the same directory then just put it in a `<Directory>` section outside of all `<virtualHost>` sections.

Comment: ... but bear in mind if someone does `Options None` or `Options -FollowSymlinks` deeper in the configuration (or in .htaccess if they're allowed to) it will override your global setting. (At least if I'm remembering my Apache conf file semantics correctly)

Comment: Also All virtualhost definitions should contain "AllowOverride All".
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the main configuration, you may can do it only for /www or something like that

```
<Directory />
Options +FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thx! What does the '+' signify?